# Recursive sequence (German Math Olympiad 2016, 2nd round)

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ be recursively defined by

$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \left(x_n + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$

and let $x_1 = \dfrac{1}{6}$

Calculate $x_{2016}$

How would you approach this? Find a closed form?

Comment: I would definitely try *something*. Which you seem to have not done.

Comment: Calculate $x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots$ ... Do you spot a pattern ? Now Prove the pattern by Induction.

Comment: The comment of @DonaldSplutterwit represents a very powerful (generic) weapon in Math problems, known as $\color{red}{\text{Elbow Grease}}.$

Comment: @user2661923 I swear to you that I don't know Elbow Grease (perhaps because I didn't learn Math in English language?) and I found nothing on google with the keyword "Elbow Grease". Could you please provide me some useful links?

Comment: This is a term that I made up to represent taking out a piece of scratch paper and manually checking values to look for a pattern and stretch your intuition.  It is a *play on words* re **movers** will use the term to describe putting in extra energy to move a box.

Comment: @NN2 you get tons of hits if you google this. There is even a wikipedia entry for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_grease

Comment: @Thomas Ok, thank you! I thought "Elbow Grease" is some kind of powerful weapon like AM-GM inequality ;).

Comment: @user2661923 interesting term ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x_2 = \frac{1}{3} $$
and
$$x_{n+1}= \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \left(x_n + \dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \left(\dfrac{n}{n+2} \left(x_{n-1} +\frac{1}{2}  \right)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow (n+3)(n+2)x_{n+1} = (n+1)nx_{n-1} +(n+1)^2$$
Denote $y_n=(n+2)(n+1)x_{n}$, then
$$y_2 = 4.3.x_2 = 4 \tag{1}$$
$$y_{2n}=y_{2(n-1)} + 4n^2 \tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$, you can deduce easily $y_{2016}$ and $x_{2016}$ is just equal to $\frac{y_{2016}}{2017.2018}$.

Comment: $x_n = \frac{n}{6}$ ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I haven't had yet the final result but it is very possible.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite straightforward: If $x_n = \dfrac{n}{6}$ then 
$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \left(x_n + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ becomes $\dfrac{n+1}{6}  = \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \left(\dfrac{n}{6} + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ which turns out to be  $\dfrac{n+1}{6}$ since the $n + 3$ cancels. So $x_{2016} = \dfrac{2016}{6} = 336$

Comment: So calculating some values and then taking an educated guess which is then to be proven true seems to be a good strategy

Comment: @spectre42 Exactly